# Urban Code Deploy doesn't start when we try to switch the current db2 database(on AIX ) to cloned db2 database in new platform(linux)

Tags: database, db2, ucd

We recently cloned our DB2 database that existed on AIX platform and created a new DB2 database in Linux platform. I can connect to the new database server from the UCD server with no firewall issues. Also user ucdadmin has all the required security rights on the new db.

I changed the parameters in the installed.properties file of ucd to replace old db to new db. hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:db2://ebimspdb01:60000/UCDP hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:db2://cwy1ebimgmt:57000/UCDP1

But after this change UCD does not start and we are getting this error:

> 2020-02-25 13:07:30,825 WARN main
>   net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.AbstractEhcacheProvider - Could not find a
>   specific ehcache configuration for cache named
>   [com.urbancode.air.workflow.DispatchedTask]; using defaults.
>   2020-02-25 13:07:31,190 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Starting HA Lock Manager... 2020-02-25 13:07:31,197 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Configuring Security System...
>   2020-02-25 13:07:31,198 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Configured authentication realms in JAAS. 2020-02-25 13:07:31,217 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:31,217
>   INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Starting Versioned
>   Configuration... 2020-02-25 13:07:31,237 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:31,253 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - No patches found. 2020-02-25
>   13:07:31,507 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Starting
>   Versioned File Storage... 2020-02-25 13:07:31,514 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:31,691 INFO
>   RecordMetadataService
>   com.urbancode.air.vc.metadata.RecordMetadataService - All versioned
>   metadata generators have been processed. 2020-02-25 13:07:31,733 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.rcl.LicenseUtil - Found server license type:
>   SERVER_AUTHORIZED 2020-02-25 13:07:31,778 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.rcl.LicenseUtil - Found server license type:
>   SERVER_AUTHORIZED 2020-02-25 13:07:31,843 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Configuring Event Service...
>   2020-02-25 13:07:31,845 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   done 2020-02-25 13:07:31,846 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer
>   - Starting calendar event scheduler... 2020-02-25 13:07:31,847 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.subsys.calendar.service.CalendarEntryNotificationService
>   - Started 2020-02-25 13:07:31,847 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:31,847 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Configuring Notifications...
>   2020-02-25 13:07:31,905 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   done 2020-02-25 13:07:31,905 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer
>   - Configuring email spooler... 2020-02-25 13:07:31,910 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:31,933 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Workflow Engine Started
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,140 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Configuring Replication... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,140 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - replication disabled 2020-02-25
>   13:07:32,141 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,141 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Configuring Replicated Codestation... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,176 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,176
>   INFO codestation.upgrader
>   com.urbancode.ds.repl.codestation.upgrade.CodestationUpgrader -
>   Upgrader Running. 2020-02-25 13:07:32,319 ERROR main
>   com.urbancode.container.tomcat.Container - Failed to start IBM
>   UrbanCode Deploy java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start IBM
>   UrbanCode Deploy at
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer.start(UDeployServer.java:598) at
>   com.urbancode.container.tomcat.Container.run(Container.java:108) at
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer.main(UDeployServer.java:351) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) at
>   com.urbancode.launcher.Launcher.invokeMainMethod(Launcher.java:247) at
>   com.urbancode.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:172) at
>   com.urbancode.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:100) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.urbancode.ds.persistence.database.DatabaseFactory.getSecuritySubcriteria(DatabaseFactory.java:57)
>   at
>   com.urbancode.ds.persistence.database.DatabaseFactory.attachSecurityCriteria(DatabaseFactory.java:74)
>   at
>   com.urbancode.ds.persistence.database.DatabaseFactory.generateCriteria(DatabaseFactory.java:135)
>   at
>   com.urbancode.ds.persistence.database.DatabaseFactory.generateCriteria(DatabaseFactory.java:179)
>   at
>   com.urbancode.ds.subsys.deploy.agent.AgentFactory.getPreFIPSAgents(AgentFactory.java:395)
>   at
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer.initSSLSettings(UDeployServer.java:705)
>   at com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer.start(UDeployServer.java:556) ... 9
>   more 2020-02-25 13:07:32,325 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer
>   - Stopping licensing... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,338 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,338 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping workflow trace
>   upgrade... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,338 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - stopped 2020-02-25 13:07:32,338 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping Background Upgraders...
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,338 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,338 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer
>   - Stopping codestation... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,338 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - stopped 2020-02-25 13:07:32,338 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping resource role
>   scheduler... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,340 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - stopped 2020-02-25 13:07:32,340 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping stack execution
>   scheduler... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,341 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - stopped 2020-02-25 13:07:32,341 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping scheduler... 2020-02-25
>   13:07:32,341 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - scheduler
>   stopped 2020-02-25 13:07:32,341 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping event service... 2020-02-25
>   13:07:32,341 WARN main com.urbancode.air.services.event.EventService -
>   13 EventListeners left registered at shutdown 2020-02-25 13:07:32,341
>   WARN main com.urbancode.air.services.event.EventService - 3
>   EventListeners left registered at shutdown 2020-02-25 13:07:32,342
>   INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - event services stopped
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,342 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,342 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer
>   - Stopping agent task processor... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,343 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,343 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping network connectors...
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,354 ERROR main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Stopping network connectors java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.urbancode.ds.security.SecuritySchemaHelper.hasAction(SecuritySchemaHelper.java:567)
>   at
>   com.urbancode.ds.security.SecuritySchemaHelper.assertAction(SecuritySchemaHelper.java:600)
>   at
>   com.urbancode.ds.network.NetworkRelayFactory.getAllNetworkRelays(NetworkRelayFactory.java:93)
>   at
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer.stopNetworkRelayConnectors(UDeployServer.java:2366)
>   at com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer.shutdown(UDeployServer.java:1247) at
>   com.urbancode.container.tomcat.Container.run(Container.java:119) at
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer.main(UDeployServer.java:351) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) at
>   com.urbancode.launcher.Launcher.invokeMainMethod(Launcher.java:247) at
>   com.urbancode.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:172) at
>   com.urbancode.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:100) 2020-02-25
>   13:07:32,354 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,354 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Stopping calendar event scheduler... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,354 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.subsys.calendar.service.CalendarEntryNotificationService
>   - Shutting down... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,354 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.subsys.calendar.service.CalendarEntryNotificationService
>   - Stopped 2020-02-25 13:07:32,354 INFO Calendar event scheduler com.urbancode.ds.subsys.calendar.service.CalendarEntryNotificationService
>   - Stopped 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - calendar events stopped 2020-02-25
>   13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Stopping repository integration service... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355
>   INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - integration service stopped
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer
>   - Stopping email spooler... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - email spooler stopped 2020-02-25
>   13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Stopping workflow engine... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping security system...
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer
>   - Stopping auditing service... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,355 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping HA lock manager...
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,365 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,365 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer
>   - Cleaning up Hibernate transactions... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,365 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - no active transaction found on
>   application shutdown 2020-02-25 13:07:32,365 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25 13:07:32,365 INFO
>   main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopping hibernate... 2020-02-25
>   13:07:32,381 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done
>   2020-02-25 13:07:32,381 INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer -
>   Releasing class loader from commons-logging... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,386
>   INFO main com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - done 2020-02-25
>   13:07:32,386 WARN main com.urbancode.container.tomcat.Container -
>   Shutting down web UI... 2020-02-25 13:07:32,397 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - * 2020-02-25 13:07:32,397 INFO main
>   com.urbancode.ds.UDeployServer - Stopped IBM UrbanCode Deploy